# how do i Assigning Timage bitmap to jpg correctly?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

i am doing the following to resize a Timage graphic and save it as jpg . the image saved blank .

here is how i assign the Timage

```
begin
 with TOpenDialog.Create(self) do
    try
      Caption := 'Open Image';
      Options := [ofPathMustExist, ofFileMustExist];
      Filter  := 'JPEG Image File (*.jpg)|*.jpg|JPEG Image File (*.jpeg)|*.jpeg|Bitmaps (*.bmp)|*.bmp';
      if Execute then
        image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(FileName);
    finally
      Free;
    end;
end;
```

and here is how i resize the timage and assigning it into a jpg .

```
 with Image2.Canvas do begin
    Lock;
    try
      try
        Image2.Picture.Graphic.Width := 50;
        Image2.Picture.Graphic.Height := 50;
        FillRect(ClipRect);
        StretchDraw(rect(0, 0, 50, 50), image1.Picture.Bitmap);
      except
        on E: Exception do
//log

      end;
    finally
      Unlock;
    end;
  end;




Jpg := TJPEGImage.Create;
try

Jpg.Performance := jpBestSpeed;
Jpg.ProgressiveEncoding := True;
Jpg.ProgressiveDisplay := True;
Jpg.Assign(image2.Picture.Bitmap);
Jpg.CompressionQuality := 90;
Jpg.Compress;
jpg.SaveToFile('screena.jpg');



finally
Jpg.Free;
end;
```

The saved jpg becomes blank what i am doing wrong ? all i needed to do is load image from disk into Timage then adjust the width and height and assign it again into a jpg

Comment: Why are you using TImage at all? That's a GUI control.

Comment: Presumably because the images are being shown to the user.  The fact that a `TOpenDialog` is being used implies that a UI is being used. In any case, `TImage2` isn't really needed, it can be replaced with a simple `TBitmap` instead: `bmp := TBitmap.Create; try bmp.Width := 50; bmp.Height := 50; bmp.Canvas.StretchDraw(rect(0, 0, 50, 50), image1.Picture.Graphic); ... Jpg.Assign(bmp); ... finally bmp.Free; end;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason your image is blank is because you are using the `Picture.Bitmap` property when drawing `Image1` onto the canvas of `Image2`:

```
StretchDraw(rect(0, 0, 50, 50), image1.Picture.Bitmap);
```

If you have NOT loaded a `.bmp` file into `Image1`, accessing the `Bitmap` property will wipe out the current image and replace it with a blank image.  This is [documented behavior](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TPicture.Bitmap):

> Use `Bitmap` to reference the picture object **when it contains a bitmap**. If `Bitmap` is referenced when the picture contains a Metafile or Icon graphic, **the graphic won't be converted ([Types of Graphic Objects](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Types_of_Graphic_Objects)). Instead, the original contents of the picture are discarded and `Bitmap` returns a new, blank bitmap**.

The [`TCanvas.StretchDraw()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCanvas.StretchDraw) method accepts any `TGraphic` object in its 3rd parameter.  You should be passing in the `Picture.Graphic` property instead of the `Picture.Bitmap` property:

```
StretchDraw(rect(0, 0, 50, 50), image1.Picture.Graphic);
```

---

On a side note: When assigning the `TOpenDialog.Filter` property, consider using the VCL's [`GraphicFilter()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.GraphicFilter) function in the `Graphics` unit:

> Returns a file filter compatible with the `Filter` property of an Open or Save dialog.
>
> Call `GraphicFilter` to obtain a value for the `Filter` property of an Open, Open Picture, Save Picture or Save dialog box. The `GraphicClass` parameter can specify one of these values: `TBitmap`, `TGraphic`, `TIcon`, `TMetafile`, or a user-defined descendant of `TGraphic`.

For example:

```
Filter := GraphicFilter(TGraphic);
```

If you are going to populate the `Filter` manually, then at the least, don't have separate entries for the different JPEG extensions.  Group them together in a single entry, eg:

```
Filter  := 'JPEG Images (*.jpg, *.jpeg)|*.JPG;*.JPEG|Bitmap Images (*.bmp)|*.BMP';
```